Chainlink Job Stuck in submit tx Task Despite Successful Transaction on Etherscan
I’m relatively new to Chainlink and I'm having trouble with my Chainlink node job. The job involves fetching data from an API, processing it, and then making a contract call using the ethtx task.The transaction seems to complete successfully, and I can verify that it is being mined on-chain by checking Etherscan. However, the Chainlink job remains stuck in the call_contract task, and the job doesn’t fully complete.
the code:
call_contract [type=ethtx 
            to="0x367E8232A9a492E7E00195B19FeDD12ce63d17C1"
            data="$(encode_data)"
            evmChainID="11155111"
            minConfirmations="2"
            gasLimit="500000"
            failOnRevert="false"
            extractResult="true"
    ]

I’ve confirmed on Etherscan that the transaction is mined successfully, and the data is being correctly processed on-chain. The Chainlink job, however, doesn’t seem to move past the call_contract task and stays in a suspended state.Is there something missing in my job configuration that could prevent the job from fully completing?
I would appreciate any guidance or advice on resolving this issue!

Can you share the url of the doc that you’re referring?

I'm sorry I didnt quite understand your question, which doc are you referring to?

I mean, are you following any particular documentation or tutorial?

You've to fund your Chainlink node address with some native token (i.e., Sepolia ETH, if you're running the Chainlink node on Ethereum Sepolia), then your submit_tx task of the node will be completed successfully.
NOTE: The node would use those native tokens to cover the gas fees required to submit the fulfillment transaction to the Chainlink Oracle/Operator contract.
